# Property length does not exist on type Observable <[]> in angular

Tags: angular

I have this service in angular which returns transcript

```
public transcript_arr =new ReplaySubject<[]>(1);
public confidence_arr=new ReplaySubject<[]>(1);
getTranscriptValue()
  {
    return this.transcript_arr.pipe(data => {return data;})
  }


getConfidenceValue()
  {
    return this.confidence_arr;
  }
```

> .ts file

```
service_transcript$: Observable<[]>;

this.service_transcript$=this.service.getTranscriptValue();

 for (var i = 0; i < this.service_transcript$.length; i++) {

 }

 this.http.post(this.baseUrl+'api/auth/post-data', formData).subscribe(response  => {

}
```

In .ts file i'm using service data for computational purpose then sending it to server but getting
this error :

> Property length does not exist on type Observable <[]> in angular
> Updated Code:

```
 const transcript_arr = [];
 const confidence_arr = [];

      this.service.getTranscriptValue().subscribe(el=>{
        for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
            if(this.hasWhiteSpace(el[i]))
            {     
              const arr_transcript = el[i].trim().split(" "); 
              for (var j = 0; j < arr_transcript.length; j++) {
                transcript_arr.push(arr_transcript[j].toLowerCase());
                confidence_arr.push(service_confidence[i]);
              } 
            }
            else
            {
              transcript_arr.push(el[i].toLowerCase());
              confidence_arr.push(service_confidence[i]);
            }
        }
      }) ;
```

Any solution to resolve this issue Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The pipe in your `getTranscriptValue` doesn't do anything, you can safely remove it altogether:

```
getTranscriptValue() {
  return this.transcript_arr;
}
```

As for the `for` loop, you need to get access to the actual data by subscribing to your `Observable` and then loop through that. Something like this:

```
this.service_transcript$.subscribe(transcripts => {
  for (var i = 0; i < transcripts.length; i++) {
     
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks i have updated my code i tried to use using subscribe but when i use trim and split getting `trim doesn't exist on type never` and i want to loop through confidence also that is returned same way as transcript in array i was able to handle it but how to use it as a observables

Comment: This happens because of the type. Replace `Observable<[]>` with `Observable<any[]>`, or better yet, if you know those will be strings, as reflected from the usage, then use `Observable<string[]>` directly. Same for `ReplaySubject<[]>`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the length of observable, not the content of that observable you should try below code,
Because this.service_transcript$ is observable and observable contains data which you need. so you can try this code.

```
this.service_transcript$.subscribe(res =>{

   for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
      // Your computation
   }
   this.http.post(this.baseUrl+'api/auth/post-data',formData).subscribe(response  => { });

 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have observable element. You cant check length there. You need to subscribe your element and inside it you should do your process

```
 this.service.getTranscriptValue().subscribe(el=>{
    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    }
  }) ;
```

Comment: Thanks i have updated my code i tried to use using subscribe but when i use trim and split getting trim doesn't exist on type never and i want to loop through confidence also that is returned same way as transcript in array i was able to handle it but how to use it as a observables